# archive_cleanup_command when is called?

Tags: postgresql

I am setting up a PostgreSQL 9.3 standby server in Streaming replication.
I configured the `recovery.conf` file with the `archive_cleanup_command`. The WAL files shipped from the master to the temporary folder with the `archive_command` are correctly saved, but are never deleted from the slave server.

I tried:

```
archive_cleanup_command = 'pg_archivecleanup /mnt/db1/incoming %r'
```

I also tried:

```
archive_cleanup_command = '/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_archivecleanup /mnt/db1_incoming_wals %r 2>>/tmp/archive_cleanup.log'
```

There is no entry in the log files (/var/log/postgres.log and  /tmp/archive_cleanup.log)

What am I missing?

Comment: This assumes that `pg_archivecleanup` is in the `$PATH` which is generally not true.

Comment: pg_archivecleanup seems to be in the $PATH (as postgres user):                           `[postgres@db2 ~]$ pg_archivecleanup --help
pg_archivecleanup removes older WAL files from PostgreSQL archives.`

Comment: @DomenicoFebbo It's in the PATH for your shell user; doesn't mean it is for the postmaster. That said, it's pretty unlikely not to be in reality, I don't think that's the problem. *Examine the PostgreSQL error log files to see what is happening*. Edit your question to add relevant log lines and comment here when done.

Comment: @CraigRinger unfortunatelly there are no entry in the logs. pg_archivecleanup is in the $PATH for the postgres user, so also for the postmaster user. In any case I modified the archive_cleanup_command, but no changes: no entry in the log files, no WAL files deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The questions asks "... when is called?". The answer is

> This optional parameter specifies a shell command that will be
>   executed at every restartpoint.

[as per the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/archive-recovery-settings.html).

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to stop and restart your standby server.  Reload does not seem to work.  By the way, since it seems you wanted to have debug message dumped to /tmp/archive_cleanup.log, you might need the -d option as well.